# Difference between two "this" c++

Tags: c++

I just want to know what is the difference between *this and this-> and when to use it. I think that *this is the current object and this-> points to the current object.

Comment: `this` is just a (special) pointer.  The syntax is the same as for any other pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` is a pointer to the current object. `*this` is the value that the pointer points to, the current object. `this->` is a shorthand for `(*this).`, e.g. `this->a` is the same as `(*this).a`.

Answer (score 1):

- `*this` is an application of the indirection operator on `this`. This expression evaluates to the object which `this` is pointing to.
- `this->` is an application of the member of pointer operator. This operator is used to dereference the pointer and select a member in one operator.

Both are described here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access

None of this is specific to the special `this` pointer. The operators apply in the same way to any pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a pointer to the current object. It is implicit in all your objects methods.

`*this` dereferences the `this` pointer `this->` is shorthand for `(*this).`

It is like the dereference and the dot (used to access a member of a struct or class but condensed into one operator.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a pointer to the current object. The `*` and `->` operators are standard pointer operators that respectively 1) dereference the pointer (returning the value pointed to), and 2) access a member of the object pointed to.

So in this case `*this` is the current object, and `this->Member` accesses the "Member" member of that object, i.e. as if doing `(*this).Member`.